# ExtJS 4.1 Rowexpander and Grid. Expand the specified item.extjs grid Rowexpander

Tags: extjs, grid

Good day!

Need help ExtJS 4.1

There is a ComboBox. There is a Grid. Grid plugged plug rowexpander.
ComboBox and Grid take data from one array.

**The purpose of the script:** after selecting an item in the ComboBox - open the corresponding rowexpander in the grid.
That is, The user selects in ComboBox «Alcoa Inc» and in the field of Grid row with the name of the company «Alcoa Inc» rowexplander is disclosed.

**Problem:** I can not turn to the records in the table and call the event expandbody / collapsebody

After selecting a ComboBox'e I get the id of the selected item, which corresponds to the id record in Grid, but also how to use it, what would appeal - I can not understand.

grid.getView (). getNode (0) - got so appeal, but it's not something that would help me.

PS So far, the variables are declared as window.grid and window.simpleCombo to simplify debugging

The script:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../examples/ux');

Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.ux.RowExpander',
    'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',
    'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager',
    'Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    'Ext.ux.SlidingPager',
    'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    'Ext.form.FieldSet'
]);

Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

    var myData = [
        ['0','3m Co',71.72,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['1','Alcoa Inc',29.01,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['2','Altria Group Inc',83.81,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['3','American Express Company',52.55,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['4','American International Group, Inc.',64.13,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['5','AT&T Inc.',31.61,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['6','Boeing Co.',75.43,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['7','Caterpillar Inc.',67.27,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['8','Citigroup, Inc.',49.37,'9/1 12:00am']
    ];

    Ext.define('Company', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        idProperty: 'company',
        fields: [
           {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'company', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
           {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
        ]        
    });

    Ext.define('State', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {type: 'int', name: 'id'},
        {type: 'string', name: 'name'}
    ]
});

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Company',
        remoteSort: true,
        pageSize: 3,
        proxy: {
            type: 'pagingmemory',
            data: myData,
            reader: {
                type: 'array'
            }
        }
    });

    // create the data store for combobox
    function createStore() {
    return Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoDestroy: true,
        model: 'State',
        data: myData
    });
}

    // create the Grid
    window.grid = Ext.createWidget('gridpanel', {
        title:'Sliding Pager',
        store: store,
        columns: [ {
                id:'company',
                text: 'Company',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'company',
                flex: 1
            },{
                text: 'Price',
                sortable: true,
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney,
                dataIndex: 'price',
                width: 75
            },{
                text: 'Last Updated',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'lastChange',
                width: 75
            }],
        stripeRows: true,
        height:320,
        minHeight: 160,
        width:700,
        frame:true, //+ 
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
        id: 'atata',
            rowBodyTpl : [
                '<p>Company: <b>{company}</b></p>',
                '<p><b>$ {price}</b></p>'
            ]
        }],
        collapsible: true,
        animCollapse: false, // end +
        resizable: {
            handles: 's'  
        },
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            pageSize: 3,
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.SlidingPager', {})
        })
    });

    grid.render('grid-example');

    function open_some_plus(val) {

    alert(grid.getView().getNode(val));

    }

    // Simple ComboBox using the data store
   window.simpleCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Select a single state',
        renderTo: 'simpleCombo',
        displayField: 'name',
        width: 700,
        labelWidth: 400,
        store: createStore(),
        queryMode: 'local',
        typeAhead: true
    });

simpleCombo.on('select', function() {
    var v = simpleCombo.getValue();
    var record = simpleCombo.findRecord(simpleCombo.valueField || simpleCombo.displayField, v);
    var index = simpleCombo.store.indexOf(record);
    open_some_plus(index);
});
    store.load();

});
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Sliding Pager Extension Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/example.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body .x-panel {
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
        .icon-grid {
            background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/grid.png) !important;
        }
        .add {
            background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/add.gif) !important;
        }
        .option {
            background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/plugin.gif) !important;
        }
        .remove {
            background-image:url(../shared/icons/fam/delete.gif) !important;
        }
        .save {
            background-image:url(../shared/icons/save.gif) !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="simpleCombo"></div>
 <div id="mydiv_id"></div>
<br/>
<div id="grid-example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me the solution, the second day of the "struggling against the wall."

Answer (score 2):

1. [opt] specify `pluginId` instead of `id`
2. use getPlugin() or `grid.plugins[0]` and "native" .toggleRow()

   ```
   plugins: [{
       ptype: 'rowexpander',
       pluginId: 'atata',
       rowBodyTpl : [
           '<p>Company: <b>{company}</b></p>',
           '<p><b>$ {price}</b></p>'
       ]
   }],

   function open_some_plus(val) {
       grid.getPlugin('atata').toggleRow(val)
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice, I had never heard of `getPlugin()` Just beware that `toggleRow()` is private and may not there in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

This code work**s**:

```
//val = 5 for example
var store = grid.getStore();
var expander = grid.plugins[0];
var page = grid.store.currentPage;
var record = store.getAt(val);
expander.toggleRow(val);
```